# Display icon when .table-responsive is horizontally scrollable in Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4, drupal, responsive

I have an icon as background in css in a responsive table with bootstrap (Drupal)

```
tablefield-wrapper .table-responsive {
padding-top: 2.5em;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: right top;
background-size: 30px;
background-image: /sites/default/files/muis-scroll.png); }
```

Is it possible to only show the icon when table is too big so that the table is horizontally scrollable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't do it with CSS only. You can use javascript to add a class with the background image to the table when its width exceeds the width of its parent:

**Javascript:**

```js
  const table = document.getElementsByClassName('table-responsive')[0];
  const wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('tablefield-wrapper')[0];
  if (table.offsetWidth > wrapper.offsetWidth) {
    table.classList.add('scrollable');
  }
```

**CSS:**

```css
.tablefield-wrapper .table-responsive.scrollable {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right top;
  background-size: 30px;
  background-image: /sites/default/files/muis-scroll.png); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
Indeed, with a little help from javascript, it works.

I did this with the page load. I just have to do it when the window resizes.